# Get first item in list of objects from array of list of objects

Tags: c#, arrays, object, dictionary

I would like to know how I can get the value for the key 'Field' which is first property in list of objects which is part of list of objects.

This is what I have:

[image]

I tried this:

```
foreach (object varObj in filters)
{
    string value =varObj[0].ToString();
}
```

also

```
foreach (object varObj in filters)
{
    string value = Enumerable.First(varObj);
}
```

But the code is complaining every time about errors.

Any idea how can I get to that member value?

Comment: Replace `object` inside `foreach` with **actual type**. Or use `var`. Currently `varObject` is `object` thus doesn't have any members you're looking for.

Comment: it won't help. It's because first object of filters is some kind of a list containing dictionairys or KeyValuePairs

Comment: Check my edit in will work for sure :)

Comment: @MajkeloDev pls check the error message http://i.gyazo.com/aea0002908fbee35421c38f4318b6e36.png Thx

Comment: @Laziale It might help us if you also post what object types you have in this nested collection.

Comment: Posted new solution - it works for sure :)

Answer (score 0):

I tested it and it works:

```
foreach (var item in filters)
        {
            var test = ((KeyValuePair<string, string>)item).Value ;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved:

```
Dictionary<string, object> firstObject = (Dictionary<string, object>)filters.First();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> var in firstObject)
            {
                if (var.Key.Equals("Field"))
                {
                    if (var.Value.Equals("IsPending"))
                    {
                        showIncomplete = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Instead of 2 ifs You can use && as AND